# Scrapy - How to save downloaded images to both file system and S3?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to scrape and download images. I would like to save the files to Amazon S3 in addition to the file system.

I have no issue configuring either of them, but does anyone know a way to configure both at the same time so files get saved to a folder locally and AWS S3 in Scrapy?

Comment: did you try to use both at the same time ?

Comment: maybe you should create two own [ImagePipelines](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#topics-media-pipeline-override) - one should use settings for local folder, and second should use settings for S3. Eventually use one standard ImagePipelines to save in local system (or S3) and second own Pipeline which use own settings to do save on S3 (or local system)

Comment: This is the approach I tried but saving two separate pipelines ended with double GET requests for each image. See my edit how I ended up resolving it.

Comment: you could add you solution as answer. it can be more readable for others. And later you can mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: do I simply answer to my own question? I am new to StackOverflow...

Comment: yes, you can answer for your own question if you find solution. And we can upvote it. And later you can mark your answer as accepted (and it adds points to your reputation)

Comment: all done as suggested. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with following solution to save the same file twice from one GET request. In `settings.py` I used below entries:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'project.pipelines.MyItemsPipeline': 300,
    'project.pipelines.MyDualImagesPipeline': 310,
}

IMAGES_STORE = 's3://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/'
AWS_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://xxx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.com'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

IMAGES_STORE_SECONDARY = '/some/path/to/folder/'
```

Then is my custom `Pipeline` inside `pipelines.py`I overwrote one method:

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.utils.misc import md5sum


project_settings = get_project_settings()


class DualSaveImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def __init__(self, store_uri, download_func=None, settings=None):
        super().__init__(store_uri, settings=settings,
                         download_func=download_func)
        self.store_secondary = self._get_store(
            project_settings.get('IMAGES_STORE_SECONDARY'))

    def image_downloaded(self, response, request, info):
        checksum = None
        for path, image, buf in self.get_images(response, request, info):
            if checksum is None:
                buf.seek(0)
                checksum = md5sum(buf)
            width, height = image.size
            self.store.persist_file(
                path, buf, info,
                meta={'width': width, 'height': height},
                headers={'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'})
            self.store_secondary.persist_file(
                path, buf, info,
                meta={'width': width, 'height': height},
                headers={'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'})
        return checksum
```

This did a trick for me. Sharing if anybody comes across the same requirements in their project.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it only with two local folders `first`, `second` but it should work with other places.

Normally you can set only one value in `IMAGES_STORE` so I created two `Pipeline`s with different settings directly in class. I replace `store_uri` in `__init__` to send to different place.

```
class FirstImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def __init__(self, store_uri, download_func=None, settings=None):
        store_uri = 'first'   # local folder which has to exists
        super().__init__(store_uri, download_func, settings)

class SecondImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def __init__(self, store_uri, download_func=None, settings=None):
        store_uri = 'second'  # local folder which has to exists
        #store_uri = 's3://bucket/images'
        super().__init__(store_uri, download_func, settings)
```

and use them both

```
'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
    'FirstImagesPipeline': 1,
    'SecondImagesPipeline': 2,
}
```

And they save the same image in two local folders `first/full` and `second/full`.

---

**BTW:** In documetation in [usage-example](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#usage-example) I found I can set different settings for different `Pipelines` using name of pipeline as prefix `FIRSTIMAGESPIPELINE_` and `SECONDIMAGESPIPELINE_`

```
FIRSTIMAGESPIPELINE_IMAGES_URLS_FIELD = ...
SECONDIMAGESPIPELINE_IMAGES_URLS_FIELD = ...

FIRSTIMAGESPIPELINE_FILES_EXPIRES = ...
SECONDIMAGESPIPELINE_FILES_EXPIRES = ...
```

but it seems it doesn't work for `IMAGES_STORE`

---

Minimal working code which you can put in one file and run `python script.py`

It downloads images from http://books.toscrape.com/ which was created by Scrapy's authors as place for learning scraping.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    # see page created for scraping: http://toscrape.com/
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/'] #'http://quotes.toscrape.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

        # download images and convert to JPG (even if it is already JPG)
        for url in response.css('img::attr(src)').extract():
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            yield {'image_urls': [url], 'session_path': 'hello_world'}

class FirstImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def __init__(self, store_uri, download_func=None, settings=None):
        #print('FirstImagesPipeline:', store_uri)
        print('FirstImagesPipeline:', settings)
        store_uri = 'first'
        super().__init__(store_uri, download_func, settings)

class SecondImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def __init__(self, store_uri, download_func=None, settings=None):
        #print('SecondImagesPipeline:', store_uri)
        store_uri = 'second'
        store_uri = 's3://bucket/images'
        super().__init__(store_uri, download_func, settings)

# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',

    # download images to `IMAGES_STORE/full` (standard folder) and convert to JPG (even if it is already JPG)
    # it needs `yield {'image_urls': [url]}` in `parse()` and both ITEM_PIPELINES and IMAGES_STORE to work
    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
        '__main__.FirstImagesPipeline': 1,
        '__main__.SecondImagesPipeline': 2,
    },            # used Pipeline create in current file (needs __main___)
    
#    'IMAGES_STORE': 'test',  # normally you use this folder has to exist before downloading
})

c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

---

**EDIT:** You can always use standard `ImagePipeline` instead of one of modified pipeline.

```
'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
    'ImagesPipeline': 1,        # standard ImagePipeline
    'SecondImagesPipeline': 2,  # modified ImagePipeline
}

IMAGE_STORE = 'first'  # setting for standard ImagePipeline
```

Comment: I tested this approach and only downside is, it runs each Pipeline separately which ends up with doing double GET requests for the same image link. I came up with a solution where I setup one pipeline with two store options instead.

Comment: you could add your solution as answer.